# Self executable Jar File not executable after installing Winrar

Tags: jar, winrar

Here's the deal, I've compiled a few classes into a jar file with a manifest pointing to the main-class. It works just fine on my computer.

I transferred the jar file onto another computer which I'm supposed to give a demonstration tomorrow on and well, here's where things went downhill.

Winrar was not installed, so I installed it in order to extract the folder I had my jar file in. I unknowingly associated winrar with jars which I fixed by changing the default open program with jre7/bin/java.exe. However, the jar file does not self-execute as it did previously. I'm thinking something's up with the registry.

Stackoverflow, what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

I guess a simple solution would be reinstalling the JRE.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately no go, I re-installed JRE but clicking on the jar still does not allow self-execution. It does self-execute on other computers. Additionally, I forgot to mention, using the command prompt java -jar MyJar.jar brings up the program just fine meaning it probably isn't a problem with how the jar is bundled or how the manifest was written. It seems to be just a problem with the registry of this new computer. - Still looking for a solution :(

Comment: Yeah, it is probably a registry mess. Did you try uninstalling WinRar?

Comment: I uninstalled WinRar, waiting for a few programs to stop running on the new computer before I restart. Hopefully a restart fixes the issues :(

Comment: When you install WinRar, you can actually choose which file extensions to open. Just be sure to uncheck *.jar next time you install WinRar. You can try to manually change the file association. In XP you do this  like this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307859

Comment: Well, it is flashing me a cannot load main class error when I try to double click the .jar, it works just fine on other computers (double-clicking/self extract). Just to be sure, I recompiled all of the jar files, but no go. Oddly, using the command prompt java -jar causes the jar file to load the main class properly.

Comment: I also have the same issue, did you get any way out

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset file association for ".jar" files, jar files are not executed by "jre7/bin/java.exe". so what you should have done before choosing default program to "jre7/bin/java.exe" was to simply uninstall WinRAR or remove its association from the WinRAR settings. So now, open start menu, search and open regedit.exe goto HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/.jar and delete every value excluding "(Default)" who's value data should be "jarfile". the reinstall jre and reboot pc . THAT'S YOUR SOLUTION.